# Index on Mysql column has lower cardinality than count distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, distinct, cardinality

I have a varchar(50) field named token. When I do

```
count(distinct token) from table
```

I get ~ 400k. However, if I do

```
create index idx on table (token)
```

The cardinality is only 200. What could be going on here? Shouldn't cardinality be the same as the number of distinct tokens?

Comment: Try using `ANALYZE TABLE table` and see if it updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cardinality is an *estimate* of the number of unique values in the index. According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-index.html):

> Cardinality is counted based on statistics stored as integers, so the value is not necessarily exact even for small tables.