# MySQL index creation

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

I am running MySQL  5.5.47-0+deb7u1-log (Debian). In a database have two tables, exactly the same structure, roughly the same data (don't ask me why, it's a long story, and I know they are wasteful), about 80M records each.

```
table1/table2(review_id int(11), adj_id int(11), occurrences int(11))
             Primary(review_id, adj_id)


adj_id has about 14000 unique values.
review_id has about 1.8M unique values. 
Both adj_id and review_id have KEY indexes to speed up search.
```

Now: Table1 was fully created first (with separate indexes on review_id, adj_id) and thereafter values were updated / inserted.
Table 2 was createdwithout any indexes first (knowing primary combination are unique) and indexes built on top.

### The indexes, it turns out are surprisingly different. Particularly adj_id cardinality 38951 vs. 24!!!!:

Table:  Keyname  Type  unique  packed  clmn    card.  coll.NULL

Table1: ind_adj   BTREE   No        No  adj_id  38951   A   No  (pre-built)

Table2: aid       BTREE   No        No  adj_id  24      A   No (post-added)

adj_id has about 14000 unique values, so the values here do not seem as an estimate of the DISTINCT COUNT value for that column.

A search by adj_id into table2 seems to be about 50% slower.

I'm very curious about this. Any explanation?

Comment: This is a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index on Mysql column has lower cardinality than count distinct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441260/index-on-mysql-column-has-lower-cardinality-than-count-distinct)